# Center Title in actionbar - kivy

Tags: kivy

Is there any chance to center title or some text in general in actionbar in kivy?

[image: What I am trying to do]

I am new in kivy so i will be happy for any help.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv=Builder.load_string("""
GridLayout:    
    cols:1
    size: root.width, root.height
    ActionBar:
        ActionView:
            minimum_width: root.width            
            use_separator: True
            ActionPrevious:
                app_icon:""
                title:"Hey"
                with_previous: False
            ActionOverflow:
            ActionLabel:
                text: "centered text"
                minimum_width:300
            ActionLabel:                
                text: "time"              
            
""")

class ButtonsApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ButtonsApp().run()
```